# How can I redirect from a Module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried TO Google *Can I redirect_to in rails modules* but couldn't come up with anything. Basically, I have a method that I am going to use across a couple of Controllers.

*lib/route_module.rb*

```
module RouteModule

    def self.user_has_active_chocolate(c_id, u_id)
        chocolate_id = c_id
        user_id = u_id
    unless UserChocolate.where(id: chocolate_id).empty?
      if UserChocolate.where(id: chocolate_id).last.active?
        true
      else
        false
        # BREAKS OVER HERE...
        redirect_to "/user/new-chocolate/#{user_id}"
      end
    else
      false
      redirect_to "/admin"
    end
  end

end
```

*app/controllers/user_controllers.rb*

```
 include RouteModule
 before_filter  :thingz, only: [:display_user_chocolate]

 # private 

 def thingz
   RouteModule.user_has_active_chocolate(params["chocolate_id"], params["user_id"])
 end
```

But... whenever I run this... It will break as soon as it hit's redirect_to.

**undefined method `redirect_to' for RouteModule:Module**

My other option is use `ActiveSupport::Concerns` but I just trouble converting this Module into a Concern.

Comment: Do you `include` this module into your controllers or call it directly?

Comment: @mudasobwa Yeah, here I updated the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include a module, it acts as a mixin. That said, you `include` and get all the methods of the module in the context of your class. The proper way would be:

```
module RouteModule
  def user_has_active_chocolate(c_id, u_id) # NO self
    ...
  end
end
```

And in the class:

```
include RouteModule 
def thingz
  # NO module method call (NO RouteModule)
  user_has_active_chocolate(params["chocolate_id"], params["user_id"])
end
```

Comment: Wow I can't thank you enough. To be honest, I didn't understand why self was even in there, I just saw it on another question, and it kinda started working. One question, if my previous way was unproper... How come it still got hit up until the redirect? Is it because it was a Mixin, and hence it doesn't have `redirect_do`?

Comment: It worked until the `redirect_to` because your were explicitly calling _module method_ with `RouteModule.user_has_active_chocolate`. One might think of it as of “alone method with no context,” java people call it `static`.